# How to add change an image's text in JS / HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, what I'm trying to do is I am trying to change an images alt "text".

In other words: I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var num = 0;
    setInterval(function(){asdfjkl.InnerHTML="Number: " + num}, 500);
    setInterval(function(){num+=1;}, 100);
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <image id="asdfjkl" src="asdf.png">Hello!</image>
  </body>
 </html>
```

But the script has no effect at all on the image's text. If someone could help that would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: alt is an attribute of image, I think `img` is a self-closing element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `image` tag is used inside `svg` elements, for HTML use `img` tag and they are self closing tags `<img src="" />`.
2. It's not `InnerHTML`, it is `innerHTML` and you don't even need to use it in your case.
3. To set the `alt` attribute of the `img`, simply use `asdfjkl.alt`.

```js
var asdfjkl = document.getElementById('asdfjkl');
var num = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  asdfjkl.alt = "Number: " + num
}, 500);
setInterval(function() {
  num += 1;
}, 100);
```

```html
<img id="asdfjkl" src="" alt="Hello!" />
```

Comment: `asdfjkl` is defined because it's an element ID, and these automatically become global variables. http://www.2ality.com/2012/08/ids-are-global.html

Comment: @Barmar - To be honest, I did not know that. Thanks! :)

Comment: Beware, using globals defined by element ids will cause you hours of headaches from simply not being explicit about what you're referencing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use img tag, instead of image. You cannot use the element id directly like this. Use getElementById("Elem ID Here"). Also innerHTML in your case is with a capitalised i. Use innerHTML not InnerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

To change the `alt` text, you need to set it first! :)

Set it like this:

```
<image id="asdfjkl" src="asdf.png" alt="abc">Hello!</image>
```

Change it like this:

```
document.getElementById('asdfjkl').alt = 'xyz';
```

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var image = document.getElementById('asdfjkl');

image.alt = 'xyz';

console.log(image);
```

```html
<image id="asdfjkl" src="asdf.png" alt="abc">Hello!</image>
```

**For your code, you need to do following 3 things:**

1. Instead of `<image>` tag use `<img>` tag.
2. Wrap your `<img>` in `<figure>` and add a `<figcaption>`.
3. Instead of fetching the image by ID, fetch the `<figcaption>` and change its `innerHTML`.

Thats it!

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var num = 0;
setInterval(function(){document.getElementsByTagName('figcaption')[0].innerHTML="Number: " + num}, 500);
setInterval(function(){num+=1;}, 100);
```

```html
<figure>
  <img id="asdfjkl" src="asdf.png" />
  <figcaption>Hello!</figcaption>
</figure>
```